# Функция strcpy - версия с указателями

Tags: c, строки, указатели

Читая книгу Брайана Кернигана по языку программирования Си понравился пример реализации функции strcpy, но немного не понимаю почему второй способ работает без `\0`

Первый способ мне понятен:

```
void copy(char *src, char *str)
{
  while ((*s++ = *t++) != '\0')
    ;
}
```

А вот второй способ без `'\0'`. Вопрос, как это работает? Почему можно не указывать символ нуля? В книге написано, что `'\0'` здесь не нужен, оно лишнее, только вот не объяснили почему :) Вопрос почему? Я думал что нужно указать какое-то условие цикла, чтобы мы не выходили за пределы, но если скомпилировать, то все работает как надо. В `list` копируется строка `Hello world` без ошибок

```
void copy(char *src, char *str)
{
  while (*s++ = *t++)
    ;
}
```

Передача аргументов

```
int main(void)
{
  char list[100];
  copy(list, "Hello world");
}
```

Просьба объясните пожалуйста простыми словами.
Можно еще по первому способу дать комментарий, заранее спасибо!

Comment: в большинстве языков программирования 0 автоматически приводится к false. поэтому цикл завершится, как только результат выражения будет 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень простыми словами - чему равно выражение `*s++ = *t++`? Оно представляет собой присвоенный символ. Значит, пока этот символ **не** нулевой, будет присваиваться следующий.

А как только скопируется нулевой символ, выражение `*s++ = *t++` станет равно нулю, и цикл завершится.

Но нулевой символ будет скопирован.

Так понятно?

В общем случае выражение

```
a != false
```

можно заменить на просто `a` - ведь если `a` не равно `false`, то оно преобразуется в `true`, чему равно и `a != false`, и проверка излишня.

При `a == false` проверка дает `false` - и она опять излишня, ибо `a` само по себе `false`!

Comment: понял! спасибо! Еще вопрос, как я понимаю это конструкция называется разыменование со смещением? или я что-то путаю?

Comment: Да как-то не интересовался, как ее назвать... Для меня это просто два оператора - разыменования и **пост**фиксного инкремента...

Comment: спасибо большое!